# Distriqt Push Notification Extension: How to know if user has not allowed PNs on first application run?

Tags: push-notification, air, distriqt

I'm using Distriqt Push Notifications Extension and I can't get it working correctly if the user does not allow PNs on first run: the application ends registering the user because it states that PNs are enabled and available.

I do the following:

```
if (PushNotifications.isSupported()) {
    registerPushNotifications();
}

private function registerPushNotifications():void {
    PushNotifications.service.addEventListener(PushNotificationEvent.REGISTER_SUCCESS, onPushNotificationToken);
    PushNotifications.service.register(MODEL.Configuration.GCM_SENDER_ID);
}

private function onPushNotificationToken(event:PushNotificationEvent):void {
    if (PushNotifications.service.isEnabled) { registerDevice(); }
}
```

Does not `PushNotifications.service.isEnabled` supposed to be false if the user disallows it? When does it become false? How am I supposed to handle this case scenario?

Comment: I've considered using a timeout, delaying registration, but it only delays the registration for an specific time; if the user does not hit Allow or Do not allow during this time, it won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what was happening in my application:

I'm handling activate/deactivate events to enable and disable background execution: `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = true;`. This makes your application able to run on background, ignoring the UI which asks for user permission and it happens that `PushNotifications.service.isEnabled` is `true` on first run after installation.

What I've done is delaying adding activation and deactivation listeners till one of this things happen first:

- The device does not support push notifications `PushNotifications.isEnabled == false`
- When the device receive a push token
- When the device fails receiving a push token

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hi, we have some example code to illustrate the best usage of this here: https://gist.github.com/marchbold/fb0438cf326a44cea0cf#file-distriqt-extensions-pushnotifications-isenabled-as

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this here for anyone else who has issues with the `isEnabled` flag:

```
var hasRequestedPermissionsOnce:Boolean = false;
// You should load hasRequestedPermissionsOnce from some persistent storage, defaulting to false 

...

PushNotifications.init( APP_KEY );
if (PushNotifications.isSupported)
{
    if (PushNotifications.service.isEnabled)
    {
        // Notifications have been enabled by the user 
        // You are free to register and expect a registration success
        register();
    }
    else if (!hasRequestedPermissionsOnce)
    {
        // You should implement hasRequestedPermissionsOnce somewhere to check if this is the first run of the app
        // If we haven't called register once yet the isEnabled flag may be false as we haven't requested permissions
        // You can just register here to request permissions or use a dialog to delay the request
        register();
    }
    else
    {
        // The user has disabled notifications
        // Advise your user of the lack of notifications as you see fit
    }
}

...

private function register():void
{
    // You should save hasRequestedPermissionsOnce to a shared object, file or other persistent storage
    hasRequestedPermissionsOnce = true;

    PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.REGISTER_SUCCESS, registerSuccessHandler );
    PushNotifications.service.addEventListener( PushNotificationEvent.REGISTER_FAILED,  registerFailedHandler );

    PushNotifications.service.register( GCM_SENDER_ID );
}
```

Original source here: https://gist.github.com/marchbold/fb0438cf326a44cea0cf#file-distriqt-extensions-pushnotifications-isenabled-as

Comment: I've used that code to check if it was the first time the application run, but I've stated in the answer I had to use another approach because I have got enabled execute in background and `isEnabled` returns true the first time, ignoring what the user has set (the truth is that the user hasn't set anything yet).

Comment: Really? Changing the execute flag shouldn't affect the registration for remote notifications. So after you set that flag isEnabled reports true and if you comment it out it returns false?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but when `PushNotifications.service.register( GCM_SENDER_ID );` is called, a popup appears requesting permission for Push Notifications and sometimes, isEnabled reports true, even though the user clicked No.

What happens behind the scenes is that `register` tries to register the device for push notifications, and when `registerSuccessHandler` gets triggered, `isEnabled` is equals `true`, but the user clicked No. I supposed that you used `hasRequestedPermissionsOnce` to avoid `isEnabled` being false the first time, but it is true, what is far more strange.

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on iOS 9.1. Is there any reported bug on that version?

Comment: It might be related with a testing device: while reinstalling several times the application (with an ad hoc mobile provisioning) the error happens occasionally. Restarting the device seems to make it work properly, although I'm not 100% sure if it's this what's happening.